# Laurent series sum for function $ \frac{z^2-2z+3}{z-2} $

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Is this sum correct?
$$
\frac{z^2-2z+3}{z-2}=((z-1)^2+2)\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-1)^{j+1}}
$$
$$
=(z-1)+1+\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{3}{(z-1)^{j+1}}
$$
I don't understand how you go from the first line to the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- first equality follows from $z^2-2z+3=(z-1)^2+2\,$
- second equality follows from

$$
\begin{align}
\big((z-1)^2+2\big)\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-1)^{j+1}} &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-1)^{j-1}}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{2}{(z-1)^{j+1}} \\
 & = (z-1)+1+\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-1)^{j-1}}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{2}{(z-1)^{j+1}}
\end{align}
$$